# get_pagination not working on a custom post type query (using WP_Query)

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop

So I have a page on my site for press releases, and the press releases are a custom post type. I'm using a custom template called `page-press.php` for the Press page, and I want to display a loop of the recent posts for this post type in it.

All is well there. However, when I set the `posts_per_page` argument to a value that should trigger pagination, I'm not getting the pagination.

I think it must have to do with where I'm calling for the pagination in relationship to the loop, perhaps, or the order of my if else logic, but I've been looking at this for so long I think I'm probably just missing the obvious by now.

Here's teh codez:

```
<div class="content">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <!-- start listing the posts -->
    <?php $a2_press_query = new WP_Query( array ( 'post_type' => 'a2_press', 'posts_per_page' => 2)); ?>
    <?php while ( $a2_press_query->have_posts() ) : $a2_press_query->the_post(); ?>
    <article class="post <?php the_ID();?>" id="post-<?php the_ID();?>">
        <header>
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <p class="post-date"><span class="month"><?php the_time('M') ?></span> <span class="day"><?php the_time('d') ?></span> <span class="year"><?php the_time('Y') ?></span></p>
        </header>
        <div class="post-content">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Read the whole post" rel="nofollow" class="button small muted read-more">Read more <em>&rarr;</em></a></p>
        </div>
    </article>
    <?php endwhile;
    // Reset Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <div class="item-list">
        <ul class="pager">
        <?php get_pagination(); ?>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <?php else : ?>

    <div class="entry-content">
        <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'appendto-2012' ); ?></p>
        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

<?php endif; // end have_posts() check ?>
</div><!--/.content-->
```

Why isn't the pagination being generated from this?

Note: everything else is working properly - it is displaying my posts from this category on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pagination is only built "well" in non-custom post-types.  Below, I'll post an article with  more detail about the more complex setup required for custom post-type pagination via the `WP_Query()` method.

But to give the direct answer to your question, it's not working because `get_pagination()` is not a method that belongs to the `WP_Query()` object, rather it belongs to the native WordPress loop and is inaccessible as you have it coded in your question.  To set it up properly, see this article:

http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/custom-post-type-pagination-chaining-method/

Comment: Awesome - thanks for the link Brian. I'll check it out.

Comment: No prob - not sure if you're a regular stack overflower, but don't forget to mark the answer accepted if it's what you're looking for so that anyone who sees this later will know how to resolve their issue if they have the same problem.

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate the link, and the explanation, but I'm hoping to see an answer that shows me how I can fix my existing beyond just a link to a reference. But thanks just the same, Brian.

Comment: LOL, there's alot of code that yo need to change in order to get it working as you're hoping.  If you like, I can copy and paste it from the article into my response...

Comment: Sad part is, I spent several hours yesterday trying to work through that, and extract the solution from the article (partly because the scenario is a bit different for me), and now I'm on to trying to resolve another issue. I'm working on a port of an entire site built in Drupal over to Wordpress.

Comment: In the end I just decided to set the post count to -1 so it displays all posts in the post type. It only needs to display like 6 right now, and it's a category that only rarely gets updated, and I can't afford to spend any more time on it. So that's that. :-P